# React. How to show data loading message on API call

Tags: reactjs

Trying to render an API call which returns an array of products.

How to show loading message on products render. (Currently the "loading" message is not being displayed)

useGetProducts.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const useGetProducts = (API) => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        async function fetchData() {
          const response = await axios(API);
          setProducts(response.data)
        }
        fetchData();
        
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return { products, error, loaded };
};

export default useGetProducts
```

ProductList.js

```
import React from "react";
import ProductItem from "./ProductItem";
import useGetProducts from "../hooks/useGetProducts";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { API } from '../constants/constants';

const ProductList = () => {
  const data = useGetProducts(`${API}?limit=9&offset=0`);

  return (
    <section className="theme-section">
      {data.loaded ? 
        <>
        {data.products && data.products.map((product) => (
          <div key={product.id}>            
            <ProductItem product={product} />
            <Link to={`/product/${product.id}`}>ver detalle</Link>
            <br /><br />
            <hr />
          </div>
        ))}
        </>
        : "loading"
      }
      
    </section>
  )
}

export default ProductList;
```

Currently the message is not being displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that you're calling `fetchData` without waiting for it, which is immediately setting `loaded` to true.

I don't think there is a need for the `fetchData` function here, so either remove it or await it:

```
const [products, setProducts] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState("");
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
      const response = await axios(API);
      setProducts(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message);
    } finally {
      setLoaded(true);
    }
  })();
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1):

set your `loaded` state to `false` when you enter in `fetchData` function and in `finally` method, update `loaded` state to `true`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        async function fetchData() {
          setLoaded(false);
          const response = await axios(API);
          setProducts(response.data);
        }
        fetchData();
        
      } catch (error) {
        setError(error.message);
      } finally {
        setLoaded(true);
      }
    })();
  }, []);
```

Comment: `setLoaded(true)` will be called in the `finally` block without waiting for the API call to complete.